# How to access the Android R.raw class programatically

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I'm trying to read in a text file in my res/raw directory with this tidbit of code:

```
public String fetchParam(String name, int index){
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.name);
    InputStreamReader isreader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isreader);
    ...
}
```

The issue lies with "R.raw.name" where name isn't being interpreted as a variable but as a member of the R.raw class called "name". So how do I go about getting R.raw.[whatever is passed in as name]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, i think I should say that if you're trying to access your resources like this, you're probably going about this the wrong way. The R class should not generally be used in this way.

However, if you really need to do what you're trying to do, you could use reflection. Note: This is not recommended as it uses a lot of overhead and will slow down you're application if used often.

Here's a code sample:

```
try
{
    int itemId = R.raw.class.getField(name).getInt(null);
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(itemId);
    InputStreamReader isreader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isreader);
} 
catch (NoSuchFieldException ex)
{
    // Handle
}
catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
{
    // Handle
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Tried this and got it to work, but I'll go by your advice and simply make a dozen individual calls

Comment: since the variables inside your R class are not dynamic, you could try to make a Map<String, Integer> on the application startup that maps string names to the resource reference. This would probably be a lot more efficient :)

Comment: I'll give it a go as soon as I get a chance! Just to make sure I have this right, I would be doing something like this `int id1 = R.raw.class.getField(fieldName).getInt(null);` for every id within `onCreate()` and then use that to read the files every time I need to fetch a parameter? EDIT: while storing all the id in a string to int map, where the strings are the names and the int the corresponding resource ID.

Comment: Again, you should refrain from using reflection unless you don't have a choice. You could just create a map and staticly reference ids from R like this: myMap.put("someName", R.raw.someName);